# Line 2 ERROR The file NuxeoCSV-USERDOC.pdf does not exist

Tags: nuxeo, nuxeo-js-client

When i want to add an attachement(csv) to a file using the addon nuxeo csv import. I got this issue:

```
Line 2 ERROR The file NuxeoCSV-USERDOC.pdf does not exist
```

This is the csv file :

```
name,"type","dc:title","dc:description","file:content","dc:nature","dc:source"
nuxeo-csv-userdoc,"File","Nuxeo CSV User documentation","This is the user guide for Nuxeo CSV","NuxeoCSV-USERDOC.pdf","procedure","http://doc.nuxeo.com"
Nuxeo-csv-sample-3,"File","Nuxeo CSV Sample","This a second file imported with Nuxeo CSV","Nuxeo-csv-sample-3.odt","article","http://doc.nuxeo.com"
```

It's demanded to make some changes in the file conf but I don't get the last line. How I'm supposed to add the path and how can I add nuxeo.csv.blobs.folder, just by pasting it?

```
Configuration :
The Nuxeo CSV addon enables users to create file documents and upload their 
main attachment at the same time. This requires to configure where the 
server will take the attachments. This is done adding the parameter 
nuxeo.csv.blobs.folder in the server nuxeo.conf and giving it a value that 
is a local path to a folder that can be accessed by the server.
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Duplicate or related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49487071/error-while-importing-a-csv-file-in-nuxeo ?
Same questions as usual: which versions of Nuxeo and the Addon?
Better describe the reproduction steps (ie: what you did).

Comment: Thanks for your feedbacks @Julien. the version of Nuxeo is 9.10 and the version of the addon is 1.7.0. For the steps, its like described in the question. here is the link of the addon "https://connect.nuxeo.com/nuxeo/site/marketplace/package/nuxeo-csv". and here the guide "https://doc.nuxeo.com/nxdoc/nuxeo-csv/"